# unbutton as custom view inside uibarbuttonitem not triggering action

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

```
let historyButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
    button.setTitle("History", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 30 / 2
    button.titleLabel?.font = Constants.Fonts.bold(size: 12)
    button.addTarget(.none, action: #selector(historyPressed), for: .allTouchEvents)

    return button
}()

fileprivate func setupNavBar() {
    navigationItem.title = "Introductions"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: historyButton)
}
```

**the button responds normally except the function "historyPressed" never gets executed**

Comment: What does `button.addTarget(.none` mean? Also please prove that you _have_ an implementation of `historyPressed` (there is none in the code you've shown).

Comment: It's been a while since I've added a button to a nav bar. Try using a target of `self` instead of `.none`.

Comment: Using `.none` to specify nil looks odd to me (and judging by matt's reaction, to him as well.) I don't know if the OS would find your historyPressed method in the responder chain, so I would suggest providing an explicit target for your action.)

Comment: as far as I know using self docent work anymore, and .none works fine with all other buttons in the project.